# Read a null terminated string from bin file

Tags: perl, binary

I want to read a string from bin file (The string start from fixed offset and is null terminated).

How can I do this in a Perl script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`seek`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html) to the right position if necessary, then use:

```
my $str;
{ local $/ = "\0"; $str = <$fh>; }
die "Premature EOF" if !defined($str) || $str !~ /\0\z/;
chop($str);
```

Comment: no, sysread should be reserved for exceptional circumstances (and doesn't make it easy to read until a nul)

Comment: Oh i missed we dont know actual read length. That simplest way then.